# Multiply in bash script according to mathrules

Tags: bash, shell

So I have an exercise in which I need to calculate a certain string.

For example the string "|| x ||| + ||". The vertical lines represent a 1. So the solution to this string needs to be 8. So I made this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
result=$(echo $1 | tr -d ' ' | sed 's/|/1+/g' | sed 's/++/+/g' | sed 's/+x/x/g' | sed 's/ sed 's/x/*/g' | sed 's/+$//' | sed 's/$/\n/' | bc)
```

But when I executed this script on the string example, the solution I got was 6.
Then I figured out it's because the script executes this: 1+1*1+1+1+1+1. So I need a way to make parenthesis between (1+1)*(1+1+1)+(1+1) but I can't figure it out.

Can anybody help me?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What operators are passed to it? Just `+` and `x`?

Comment: Using `sed` six times in a row instead of once with 6 operations is not optimal.  The `tr` is unnecessary too; `sed` is perfectly capable of fixing spacing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to stick to sed then the best is to put in the parens *before* doing the rest:

```
result=$(echo $1 | tr -d ' ' | sed -e 's/\(|*\)/(\1)/g' -e 's/|/1+/g' -e 's/+)/)/g' -e 's/x/*/g' | bc)
```

Comment: Nice, though in the first `-e` argument I suggest you use `\{1,\}` to emulate extended-regex duplication symbol `+`  and make do without a capture group and simply use `&` to represent the whole match in the substitution; this would allow you to ditch the `tr` command altogether: `result=$(echo "$1" | sed -e 's/|\{1,\}/(&)/g' -e 's/|/1+/g' -e 's/+)/)/g' -e 's/x/*/g'| bc)`

Comment: This was the kind of answer that helped me out a lot, thanks!

Comment: @mklement0 : although your suggestion works only with gnu sed, it's a very good point and worth to remember. Thanks!

Comment: @LaszloLadanyi: My pleasure; actually, my suggestion should work with any POSIX-compliant `sed`, such as with the BSD `sed` that comes with OS X. What I'm using is a [POSIX BRE (basic regular expression)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03), which is the only type of regex that a POSIX-compliant `sed` can be expected to implement. By contrast, if I had used `\+` in lieu of `\{1,\}`, you would have been correct (`\+` in _basic_ regular expressions is a _GNU_ extension).

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work quite well:

```
{
echo "|x|+|"
echo "| x | + |"
echo "|| x ||| + ||"
echo "||x ||| +||"
echo "((|||x|||||-||||||)+|)/||"
echo "(((|||x|||||-||||||)+|)/||)^|||||"
} |
sed -e 's/||*/&)/g' \
    -e 's/|\(|*\)/(1\1/g' \
    -e 's/|/+1/g' \
    -e 's/x/*/g' |
tee converted.log |
bc
```

Sample output:

```
$ bash calc.sh
2
2
8
8
5
3125
$
```

Contents of `converted.log`:

```
(1)*(1)+(1)
(1) * (1) + (1)
(1+1) * (1+1+1) + (1+1)
(1+1)* (1+1+1) +(1+1)
(((1+1+1)*(1+1+1+1+1)-(1+1+1+1+1+1))+(1))/(1+1)
((((1+1+1)*(1+1+1+1+1)-(1+1+1+1+1+1))+(1))/(1+1))^(1+1+1+1+1)
```

The `sed` script replaces each sequence of one or more pipe symbols with the same sequence and a close parenthesis; then it replaces the pipe at the start of a sequence of pipe symbols with `(1`; then it replaces each remaining pipe with `+1`; and finally it replaces the `x`'s with `*`'s.  It only requires that the pipes are consecutive with no spaces between them.  Even that constraint can be removed by simply deleting all the spaces before doing the rest of the work.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one that works on your sample data:

```
echo "|| x ||| + ||" | tr -d ' ' | \
awk -F "+" '{out="("$1; for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){out=out")+("$i}; print out")"}' | \
awk -F "x" '{out="("$1; for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){out=out")*("$i}; print out")"}'| \
sed 's/|/1+/g' | \
sed 's/+)/)/g' | \
bc
```

I used `awk` to separate things and wrap them in parens; usually it uses a space as a separator, but I overrode it the `-F` flag.

Comment: Thanks, helped me out a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need parentheses if you translate the `|` groups into decimal numbers first - then the arithmetic operator precedence will work as usual:

```
# Assign string to $1
set -- '|| x ||| + ||'

result=$(echo "$1" | 
  awk '{ 
        for(i=1; i<=NF; ++i) {
          if ($i ~ /^\|+$/) { $i = length($i) }
          else if ($i == "x") { $i = "*" }
        }
        print
      }' | bc)
```

- Only a *single* (`awk`) command is needed for the transformation: it translates the input into `2 * 3 + 2`, which `bc` then evaluates as desired (contrast this with the OP's solution attempt and [miken32's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33817137/45375), which use *6* and *5* intermediate commands, respectively).

  - `for(i=1; i<=NF; ++i)` loops over all whitespace-separated fields in the input line.
  - `if ($i ~ /^\|+$/) { $i = length($i) }` replaces each run of `|` chars. with its length, effectively replacing it with the number it represents.
  - `else if ($i == "x") { $i = "*" }` replaces `x` with `*`, because `bc` expects `*` as the multiplication symbol.
  - by assigning to the input fields (`$i`), the input line is rebuilt with the new values, and `print` simply prints the resulting line.

Comment: Thanks but I didn't need to do it with awk, but it helped me out for in the future!!

Comment: @DriesCoppens Glad to hear it. While your question was quite specific, it's still better to _explicitly_ state requirements, such as needing the solution to use `sed`. That said, the existing answers now span 3 technologies (`sed, `awk`, and pure `bash`), which may help others too.

Answer (score 2):

EDITED to follow the suggestion in the comment (by mklement0).

Here is how I would do it:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -ra flds <<< '|| x ||| + ||'

# for each substring in string
for c in "${flds[@]}"
    do
        # compute string length
        len=${#c}
        # if the first char in c is a | then the corresponding length is the number, append it to a string
        if [[ "${c:0:1}" == "|" ]]; then str=$str"$len"
        # check for + and * and append them to the string
        elif [ "${c:0:1}" == "+" ]; then str=$str"+"
        elif [ "${c:0:1}" == "x" ]; then str=$str"*" 
        fi
    done
#evaluate the string via bc
echo "$str"|bc
```

Comment: My pleasure; your solution works well with the given input, but using `for` with an unquoted string for word-splitting is fragile in general - if the input contained `*`, for instance, it would be pathname-expanded. A better approach is to use `read`  for splitting and reading into an array first, and then `for` to safely loop over the resulting array: `read -ra flds <<<'|| x ||| + ||'` to split, and 
`for c in "${flds[@]}"` to iterate.

Comment: Yep, I edit my answer. Just one thing, I tested it and works perfectly but the syntax highlight went away. I just copied the lines from your comment. Any idea?

Comment: Thanks you guys for your time!

Comment: @terencehill I missed the syntax-highlighting part of your response: looks like it's back now; At least while editing, it takes a few seconds of idle time to kick back in; when in doubt, you can always use an explicit syntax hint, followed by at least 1 empty line: ` <!-- language: bash -->`

Comment: @mklement0 Actually didn't work on my vim too. But now it's fine. thanks again